# How do I return a list of all the prefixes of a given list?

Tags: haskell, fold

I'd like to write a function only using foldr that returns a list of all the prefixes of a given list. So if the list is `[4,5,6]` I would return `[[],[4],[4,5],[4,5,6]]`. So far I have

```
preFix :: [a] -> [[a]]
preFix x = foldr preFixHelp [[]] x

preFixHelp :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
preFixHelp x acc = [x] : acc
```

but that only returns `[[4],[5],[6]]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is already a function that does that in the standard libraries: [`Data.List.inits`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.1/base-4.13.0.0/Data-List.html#v:inits)

```
>>> inits "abc"
["","a","ab","abc"]
```

---

If you wanted to implement it yourself for some reason, and only using fold (homework?), the way to think about it is this: (1) all prefixes of an empty list is a list containing just an empty list. Let's write that down:

```
prefix [] = [[]]
```

(2) all prefixes of a list that consists of a head `x` and a tail `xs` would be the same as all prefixes of `xs`, but with `x` prepended to each, plus an empty list. Let's write that down:

```
prefix (x:xs) = [] : [x:pref | pref <- prefix xs]
```

Let's test this out:

```
>>> prefix [1,2,3]
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

So far so good.

Now, a linearly recursive algorithm like that can be easily turned into a `foldr` if you notice that:

```
foldr f z [x0, x1, ... xn]   ==   f x0 (f x1 ... (f xn z)...)
```

(this is straight from [the docs](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.1/base-4.13.0.0/Prelude.html#v:foldr))

In other words, each call of the function receives the "current" list element as the first parameter and the result of the previous function call as the second parameter, and this is just what our recursive case above needs:

```
prefix (x:xs) = [] : [x:pref | pref <- prefix xs]
                      ^                ^^^^^^^^^
                      |                |       |
                   current element     +--- ---+
                                           |
                                          result of the previous call
```

So we can easily rephrase this recursive function in terms of `foldr` like this:

```
prefixFold :: [a] -> [[a]]
prefixFold = foldr go [[]]
    where
        go x previousResult = [] : [x:pref | pref <- previousResult]
```

Comment: IOW, `foldr ((([] :) .) . map . (:)) [[]]`. :)

Comment: @WillNess way to help a beginner! :-))

Comment: exactly. :))))) wait, I should've posted that as an answer! (some "Alien" smileys in that pointfree code, huh.) ---- BTW, `foldr f z [x0, x1, ... xn]   ==   f x0 (foldr f z [x1, ... xn])` might be less confusing to said beginner.